# how to use regular expression to include file with postfix (.h, .hpp and .hxx) in cmake?

Tags: cmake, glob

I want to install all the header file under a directory.

i know regular expression can do that. but i do google a lot, not found how to include these three kind of file together.

I used command like this:

```
file(GLOB INFRA ${LOCAL_SRC_PATH}/infra/*.h[|p|x][|p|x])
```

to make `INFRA` variable to save all header file, but i found it ignore `.h`

I know this is quite easy, can you kindly help on this?

Comment: Note, that `file(GLOB)` uses **globbing expressions**, not *regular* ones. As far as I know, choice operator (`|`) does not belong to the globbing syntax. Assuming you have a list of possible extensions: `set(headers_ext .h .hpp .hxx)` you could create a list of globbing expressions for find these headers: `list(TRANSFORM headers_ext PREPEND "${LOCAL_SRC_PATH}/infra/*" OUTPUT_VARIABLE headers_glob)` and use it in the globbing command: `file(GLOB INFRA ${headers_ext})`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev thanks, glob is different with regular expr, got it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A globbing expression is not a regex; you need to use 3 separate commands to match `.h`, `.hpp` and `.hxx` files. Even as a regex this would fail, since the character groups match characters `|`, `p` and `x`, but they don't match the empty string.

In this case you'd probably use

```
set(PATH_PREFIX "${LOCAL_SRC_PATH}/infra/*")
file(GLOB INFRA_H "${PATH_PREFIX}.h")
file(GLOB INFRA_HPP "${PATH_PREFIX}.hpp")
file(GLOB INFRA_HXX "${PATH_PREFIX}.hxx")

set(INFRA ${INFRA_H} ${INFRA_HPP} ${INFRA_HXX})
```

In this case I recommend using `install(DIRECTORY)` though; this also allows you to use a regex instead of a globbing expression:

```
install(DIRECTORY "${LOCAL_SRC_PATH}/infra"
        TYPE INCLUDE
        FILES_MATCHING REGEX ".*\\.(h|hpp|hxx)")
```

Comment: you can also list glob patterns in the `file` function so you don't have to append them together later. Example: `file(GLOB HEADES "*.h" "*.hpp")`